# Sublime Text 2 REPL run iPython file with a user Plug-in

Tags: sublimetext2, ipython, sublimerepl

I am trying to run an iPython file in an interactive shell in Sublime Text 2. This is my first plugin I've written.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

    class IpydevCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
        def run(self):
            self.window.run_command('repl_open',{"type": "subprocess",
                                                 "encoding": "utf8",
                                                 "cmd": ["ipython", "-i", "$file_basename"],
                                                 "cwd": "$file_path",
                                                 "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                                                 "external_id": "ipython",
                                                 })
            self.window.run_command('move_to_group', { "group": 1 })
```

The issue here is that I don't get an interactive environment after. The view is all messed up. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: you should do this with a macro instead of a plugin...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running a notebook, you can directly call ipython using following configuration at the keymap bindings:-

[

{ "keys": ["f9"], "command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python - IPython",
                     "id": "repl_python_ipython",
                     "mnemonic": "p",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "autocomplete_server": true,
                        "cmd": {
                            "osx": ["python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                            "linux": ["python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                            "windows": ["python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"]
                        },
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {
                            "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8",
                            "SUBLIMEREPL_EDITOR": "$editor"
                        }
                    }
                    }
 ]

So, By clicking F9, it will open ipython on new shell